# What does the error mean, 'newDirectory is not defined'? I did define it

Tags: python-3.x, function-call

I am writing a tool to automate everyday processes, although when I execute my code I get a prompt asking what option I want to use, so I'll select option two, then input the directory path, then I get a NameError 'newDirectory' is not defined, despite the fact that is is defined.

I've tried calling the function in different function block e.g the main function and the pre-defined function "def newdirectory(directPath)". No matter where is call the function I always get the same error.

```
if user_response == "1":
    def newDirectory(directPath):
        if os.path.exists(directPath) == True:
            print ("The directory ", directPath, " already exists")
        else:
            os.mkdir(directPath)
            if os.path.getsize(directPath) > 0:
                print ("The directory: ", directPath, " has been successfully created")
            else:
                print (directPath, " has not been created")

def main():
    directPath = input("Enter the directory to be created: ")
    newDirectory(directPath)
```

I am expecting to be able to execute functions in my tools 'make/remove directories' without errors.

Comment: try removing the `if` statement

Comment: You shouldn't nest a function declaration in an `if`.  Also what is `user_response` at run time? If it is not  `"1"` then you do not declare your function.

Answer (score 1):

You define a function `newDirectory`, but only if the `if` statement runs. The function `newDirectory` is never defined - never put into the namespace - if `user_response` is anything other than the value `"1"`. The `NameError` you're getting now is python's standard response to something not existing in the local namespace because it was never defined.

In general, you don't put function declarations inside conditionals - simply defining a function doesn't mean it will necessarily execute, and it's better to put *calls to* the function in conditionals rather than putting the *function itself* in a conditional, precisely to avoid this error.